# Find all whole number $k$ with the property: $k$ is equal to the arithmetic mean of all the numbers obtained from all the possible permutation of $k$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, means

The exact question is here
A whole number is equal to the arithmetic mean of all the numbers obtained from the given number with the aid of all possible permutation of its digits. Find all whole numbers with that property.

**Answer**

Take $k=a_n\cdot10^{n-1}+a_{n-1}\cdot10^{n-2}+\dots+a_2\cdot10^1+a_1\cdot10^0$
The sum of all the possible permutation of k is:
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{m}\cdot(a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_1)\cdot\underbrace{111\dots111}_{n\text{  1's}}$$
With $m$ being the divisor if any of $a_n, a_{n-1}, \dots , a_1$ are the same.

The average of all the possible permutation of k would be:
$$\frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{m}\cdot(a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_1)\cdot\underbrace{111\dots111}_{n\text{  1's}}}{\frac{n!}{m}}\\=\frac{\underbrace{111\dots111}_{n\text{  1's}}\cdot(a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_1)}{n}\\=k=a_n\cdot10^{n-1}+a_{n-1}\cdot10^{n-2}+\dots+a_2\cdot10^1+a_1\cdot10^0
$$

Now i got the mean, however I'm not sure how to continue.
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you're almost over. The number of the LHS of yours, is an $n$ digits number if and only if the mean of $a_1,...,a_n$ is a one-digit number. In this case, you have two numbers written in base 10 in both sides of the equation, thus they are equal only if all of their digits are equal. The digits of the number on the LHS are all the same (it's a digit times $11...1$). To sum up, you got that the only such numbers are $k=aa..a$, for some $1\le a\le 9$.

Comment: What are the Permutations of 12321 ? What will be the average ?

Comment: @Amit I see, I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Prem I believe the permutations of 12321 would be 11223, 11232, 11322, ..., 32211 and based on the formula I got, the average would be $\frac{11111\cdot(1+2+3+2+1)}{5}=\frac{99999}{5}$

Comment: So when we have repetition , there is no Problem. I am not what your $m$ is , though. Should we not use $(n+1)!$ when Counting from $1$ to $n$ ? thinking ....

Comment: @Prem I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what you meant.

Comment: [Eg1] , $123$ , $132$ , $213$ , $231$ , $312$ , $321$ , average is $2!(1+2+3)111/6=222$ : Is my Calculation Correct ? [Eg2] $112$ , $121$ , $211$ , average is $(112+121+211)/3=444/3$ , though I am not sure what average the formula gives $2!(1+1+2)111/6$ ?

Comment: @Prem Yeah, the calculation is correct. The results are the same with mine. $\frac{111\cdot(1+2+3)}{3}=222$ and $\frac{111\cdot(1+1+2)}{3}=\frac{444}{3}$

Comment: @Amit the average of $a_i$ has to be in $[1, 9]$ (and is of course rational) but why does it have to be an integer?

Comment: @Amit For example, for $3$ digits (note that $3$ divides $111$), solutions include $k = 481$, $518$, $592$, $629$ (and $370$, $407$ if zeros are allowed). If $n$ is coprime to $(10^n - 1)/9$ then the only solutions are of the form you describe.

Comment: In general, the solutions are included in the multiples of $r/\gcd(r, n)$ in the range $[r, 9r]$ with $r = 111\dots 1 = (10^n - 1)/9$, but not all such multiples are solutions. It seems hard to control the sums of digits of these multiples.

Comment: Also whether repetitions count multiply is irrelevant since each permutation would be counted with the same multiplicity, keeping the average the same. A more interesting clarification is whether some digits are allowed to be 0, so that some permutations have leading 0s. If these are not allowed, the question is probably much harder.